# I have created my django models want to know how i can correct the do that i can see only individual employee information not all

Tags: django-models

I have created modees for my project which is Employee management . but i am facing some issues .

1: In Breaks table, its showing all employees information .But i want the user who is logged in can enter break, this problem is same for attendance table employee table.

Models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    eid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=1)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name


class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attendance_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    in_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    out_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)


class Breaks(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    break_in = models.TimeField(null=True)
    break_out = models.TimeField(null=True)
```

I am expecting when an employee logged in and enter his/her break should see her on profile not all employees .

Please check mu models and let me know how what changes are required.

Comment: Can you show the code responsible for creating breaks?

Answer (score 0):

put (user = request.user) in every filter query like this

```
show_emp = Breaks.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: This is my funnction:def addattendance(request):
    form = AttendanceForm()
    emp_list = Employee.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('/detail_attendance')  . Also error comes up user is not in the fields of the model